# Set a UIView as the background of a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uiview, background, uitabbar

I know how to customize the background *color* or the background *image* of a `UITabBar`:

```
tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor ...];     // set background color
tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage ...];  // set background image
```

Unfortunately I have not found any option how to set a **`UIView`** as the background of a tab bar in the docs. Is there a way how I can achieve that?

Comment: What actually you're trying to achieve? Do you want to have transparent view on top?

Comment: could you please tell us what exactly you are trying to do? it will help us...

Comment: I have a `UIView` with a custom `-drawRect` method that draws a gradient for example. I want to use that view as a background of the tab bar. If I can "skin" my tab bar with an image I do not understand why there seems to be no option to use a simple view instead.